# Navbar menu with large dropdown

Tags: html, css, navbar

I need to create menu like shown in this screenshot:

[image: navbar image]

So as you can, the cursor hover opens large sub menu with two sub sections. Will be glad for any similar examples to my issues. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example to get you started. It needs more styling of course and more content, but this should give you all the tools to have a dropdown on hover in your menu

HTML:

```
<header>
  <a href="/url">
    Hover to see dropdown
  </a>
  <div>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}

header > a {
  padding: 0 2em;
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

header > div {
  display: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

a:hover + div {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It utilizes the `:hover` attribute in the navbar tab 'Dropdown' to reveal more content (in this case it'll be just some links).

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

You can find more information on the [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp) website for more!